# Pusher not working on Godaddy Server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, pusher, laravel-5.4

Below are the points investigated by me so far.

In pusher Debug Console Tab, I can see the below events when page loads first time..

[image]

Below is the message in laravel.log file

> [2017-03-04 20:00:29] local.ERROR: exception
>   'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException' with message 'Timestamp
>   expired: Given timestamp (2017-03-04T20:00:28Z) not within 600s of
>   server time (2017-03-04T19:49:50Z)

When I send message from local it works perfectly and when I send message from godaddy server...it does not even appear in Debug console.

Finally I started to search on this issue and found this link: [Pusher on route not sending event in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901177/pusher-on-route-not-sending-event-in-laravel)

Other person found timezone as the root cause of such kind of issues.

I am still confused that if timezone is the issue in my case also...How could I fix it, I am using Cron Job using CPanel.

Any suggestion?

Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using log as queue driver and there was no queue setup for that. Then I checked Queue Driver to sync and everything worked. lol.